# Node JS persist promises upon restart (maybe with versioning)

Tags: node.js, promise, persistence, bots

Imagine building a bot, that handles dialogs as promise chains in nodejs

```
bot.ask('question')
    .then(answer => { ...someDataAndCode })
    .then(somethingElse)
    .then(etc);
```

Now, upon deploying the new version, all the promises are gone, of course, and then you have hung dialogs where bot doesn't reply. The questions are:

- Is there any npm package/approach that would persist promises between restarts?
- In case logic of that persisted promise updates, is there package that would keep persisted promise old version, so that "old dialogs go the old way"?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with any persistent promise module, and I think it would be very difficult to keep the state of each chained promise....

But any way, I would follow another approach to your problem. I would not kill the previous server, but I would run the new updated version in a different port. Then I would configure the reverse proxy (I assume you use something like nginx to route the traffic to node) to send all the new users to the new version of the node server.

When the old node server has finished its work and even the last user has gone, then you can kill that server.

**P.S All of this depends on the assumption that you are using a reverse-proxy, something you don't state in the question, so my solution could not fit in your project**

Comment: Will this mean that existing users almost never get new version?

Comment: Why? The old server will eventually end the logic for a user, then if the user comes again it will hit the new server...